# Android - Теряется запись из БД

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite, cursoradaper

Очень интересная проблема. Имею ListView с кастомным CursorAdapter. При создании адаптера передаю ему 2 курсора:

```
Cursor structure = SQLD.query("Structure",
            new String[]{"_id", "NumNote", "Type"},
            "DATE = "+Date, null, null, null, null, null);
    Cursor texts = SQLD.query("Texts",
            new String[] {"_id", "NumNote", "Text"},
            "DATE = "+Date, null, null, null, null, null);
    CustomCursorAdapter CCA = new CustomCursorAdapter(this, structure, texts);
```

Таблица Structure выглядит вот так:
[image: Таблица structure]

Дальше в конструкторе я вызываю конструктор суперкласса и передаю ему курсор structure:

```
public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor structure, Cursor inTexts) {
    super(context, structure, 0);
```

То есть методам newView и bindView будет передаваться этот курсор. И теперь если проверить в любом из этих методов содержание курсора, то 3 строка выбросится:

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        Log.i("CursorAdapter", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("NumNote"))+" "+
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Type")));
    }
```

Вывод в logcat:

```
I/CursorAdapter: 0 Text
I/CursorAdapter: 0 Text
I/CursorAdapter: 1 Text
I/CursorAdapter: 1 Text
I/CursorAdapter: 2 Text
```

Причем если проверить курсор, который передавал конструктору кастом адаптера, то всё нормально, я в ступоре.

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что отсутствует именно третья строка? Я думаю, что отсутствует первая и связано это с начальным позиционированием курсора. При получении указатель курсора находится перед первой строкой и для извлечения данных его нужно установить на начало, а потом уже итерировать дальше

Comment: вы создаете Cursor texts, а дальше в конструкторе работаете с Cursor inTexts, это случайно или задумка такая?

Comment: @ZigZag, да, задумка, ну точнее имя неудачное :)

Comment: @pavlofff, да, действительно теряется первая строка и связано это с начальным позиционированием, только при получении указатель курсора уже стоит на первой строке, поэтому устанавливать его на начало лишнее. Спасибо за ответ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно, у вас отсутствует не третья, а первая строка. Убедиться вы можете просто выводя id в лог.
Перед первой итерацией вам нужно сделать `cursor.moveToFirst()`

Comment: и правда, теряется первая запись без movetofirst, очень странное поведение, как по мне, спасибо за ответ

Comment: а, всё стало ясным, при получении указатель у курсора уже стоит на первом месте, поэтому вызов movetofirst - лишнее. Просто буду использовать дальше цикл с постусловием